# Link in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm struggling to create link  in blade template in Laravel.
I will pass the URL in template from environment variable.

The output suppose to be like.

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Visit Google</a>
```

I am trying sth like this but with no luck.

```html
<a href="{{env('APP_URL')}}">Visit my site</a>
```

Laravel Framework 5.5.19

Thank you

Comment: In the `.env` file did you update the `APP_URL`?

Comment: Yes, it's updated. It is correct string. I `var_dump`ed it

Comment: `{{ env('APP_URL') }}` works for me. Try deleting `.env` file and add it again

Comment: Why are you not using simply **/** or **url('/')** ? Is the homepage route different from base path.?

Answer (score 15):

Use the Laravel helper `url()`

For a link to the home page:  `<a href="{{ url('/') }}">Visit Google</a>`

From Laravel docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url